# flutter: top of image deleted in stack widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to use stack in my widget tree:

```
  body: Center(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            // card view
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 200,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20.0, bottom: 50.0, left: 50.0, right: 50.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: color_transparent_black,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: -60,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: width * 0.3,
                height: height * 0.2,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/ic_setting.png"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

And this result is this:

[image]

Why top of setting icon has been deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem:

```
 body: Center(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Stack(
        // overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            // card view
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 200,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 80.0, bottom: 50.0, left: 50.0, right: 50.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: color_transparent_black,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
            ),

          ),
          FractionalTranslation(
            translation: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: width * 0.3,
                height: height * 0.2,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/ic_setting.png"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

and it is result:

[image]

I increases **Top margin** to `top: 80.0` and replace `Positioned` with **FractionalTranslation**. Actually it works with **Positioned** too.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely because you set the `top: -60`  for the `Positioned` widget.

*Edit 1:*

Stop clipping by removing `SingleChildScrollView`

And you can center all children of `Stack` using `alignment: Alignment.topCenter` property of `Stack` widget itself.

```
 child: Center(
     child: Stack(
         overflow: Overflow.visible,
         alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
         children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                   height: 200,
                              ...
              ),
              Positioned(
                   top: -60,
                   ...
                   child: Container(
                               ...
                   ),
              ),
      ),
 ]),
```

Comment: I want the photo to be higher than the Container @AlanC

Comment: I tried removing the `SingleChildScrollView` and it does not clip the image anymore.